# objective C - using a non static method in the class implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to set a web service URL for an iPhone
The logic should be:
at login view - has service URL been set? , if so use saved default, if not prompt.

webServiceCall.h

```
@property (nonatomic,weak) NSString *webServiceUrlStr; 
// getter and setter for webServiceUrlStr
- (NSString *) webServiceUrlStr;
- (void) setwebServiceUrlStr: (NSMutableString *) theUrl;
```

webServiceCall.m

```
- (NSString *) webServiceUrlStr
{
    return _webServiceUrlStr;
}


- (void) setwebServiceUrlStr: (NSMutableString *) theUrl
{
   _webServiceUrlStr = theUrl;
   NSLog(@"Setting webServiceUrlStr = %@",_webServiceUrlStr);
}
```

In my loginviewcontroller I call this:

```
if([self.webServiceCall webServiceUrlStr] != nil)
{
    ....set view stuff here
}
```

which works ok.
Now I have set the URL from my view I want to use it in WebServiceCall Class

webServiceCall.m

```
//Basic method for calling a webservice with soap
+ (NSData *) callWebMethodWithSoapAction:(NSString*) soapAction withSoapEnvelop:     (NSString *) soapEnvelop
 {
  NSString *wsURL = [self webServiceUrlStr]; <-- No Known class for selector 'webServiceUrlStr'
  NSURL *webserviceUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:wsURL];
....etc
```

making webServiceURLStr static solves the above error but then makes the method unknown to my loginviewcontroller

Comment: Why is `callWebMethodWithSoapAction:withSoapEnvelop:` static? Make it an instance function.

Comment: When you declare a property in Objective-C your getter and setter will be automatically synthesized/generated.  Unless you want to add additional behaviour e.g. beyond setting/retrieving the variable to the getter/setter you don't need to implement them yourself.  You can therefore remove your definitions of webServiceUrlStr and setwebServiceUrlStr: from WebServiceCall.m.

Comment: you can not use `Instance` methods/variables in `Class` method. you need to create instance of Class and call your method. Better option create a `SharedInstance` of your class `webServiceCall` and use it to access variables or methods in `Class` method.

Comment: Also, your property's memory management attribute is specified to be weak, which is most likely incorrect.  Typically you will want to use retain when storing references to objects, or better yet copy when dealing with potentially mutable objects like NSStrings (which could be a NSMutableString instance).

Comment: @mostruash  ... not my decision , the code is someone else's, It has been given to me ...with the instruction "make it work"  ... my experience wit objective c ? all of 6 days worth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies... this was solved by doing the following

WebServiceCall.m , I declared a static var

```
static NSString *webServiceUrlStr
```

:
then change getters and setters to static and refer the new variable

```
+ (NSString *) webServiceUrlStr
  {
    return webServiceUrlStr;
  }


 + (void) setwebServiceUrlStr: (NSMutableString *) theUrl
 {
    webServiceUrlStr = theUrl;
    NSLog(@"Setting webServiceUrlStr = %@",_webServiceUrlStr);
  }
```

in my loginViewController class:

```
// static ref
if([WebServiceCall webServiceUrlStr] != nil)
{
   ....set view stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Static method defined on object when the method doesn't need any STATE of object. `callWebMethodWithSoapAction:withSoapEnvelop:` definetly needs object state - `webServiceUrlStr`, so it should not be static. If there is only one `webServiceCall` object needed - use singletone pattern or just global varialbe with this string value